# List symbols of current running process

Tags: c, linux, elf, symbol-table

How can I find the list of symbols of the running linux process? Basically what `nm` does, but in run time, without the need to read the binary file.

Comment: Have looked in the `/proc` filesystem (and for the own process, `/proc/self`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  That information is not loaded into RAM from the executable image.  In fact, it might not be present at all, if the binary has been "stripped".  Debuggers do exactly what `nm` does: they open and read the binary file.

(Footnote: a *subset* of the running process's symbols may be loaded into memory for use by the dynamic loader.  But there's no supported way to get a list of them.)

Comment: Thanks, but actually you can do it, at least in some limited way with `dl_iterate_phdr`

Comment: @frozen Huh, I knew about that but I thought it was not supported for external use.